# Docker duda sobre funcionamiento y aplicación

Tags: aplicación-web, docker, contenedores

Estoy probando y empezando a estudiarme los componentes docker, y me pregunta es si es adecuado usarlo para un entorno de producción. La siguiente pregunta es si se puede configurar lo suficiente desde un file, me refiero a la funcionalidad de lanzar los contenedores desde fichero y que sea totalmente seguro y estable para un entorno en producción. Les agradecería que me arrojaran algo de luz al tema. He estado haciendo pruebas y he conseguido lanzar un contenedor con un fichero pero algo muy muy básico y me surgen las dudas de por ejemplo  seguridad, usar protocolos https, configuraciónes de apache para un servidor web  en produccíon etc..

Actualmente trabajo con control de versiones y veo una método de trabajo muy interesante y rentable reduciendo costes en el lanzamiento en producción para los problemas que todos conocemos (versiones del sistema, versión de php en mi caso, etc...).

Comment: Repuesta corta: Sí. Puedes configurar todo desde los Dockerfile y puedes usar `docker-compose` para gestionar varios contenedores (base de datos, servidor web, etc.). No te preocupes por la seguridad ni por nada de eso, puedes hacer exactamente lo mismo que harías sin usar contenedores. Todo, incluído los Dockerfile y el archivo de `docker-compose`, se puede versionar.

Comment: añado al comentario de @César, si el control de versión lo tenes en github o gitlab podes automatizar el build y deploy con [gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html), [travis CI](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) ó [drone](http://docs.drone.io/images/).

Comment: Gracias por la aportación. Entiendo que el nivel de porsnalización ha de ser alto del docker file. He estado buscando y he encontrado algunas páginas dónde he encontrado algo de información sobre como ir configurando el file. Tenéis alguna página de referencia o documentación dónde este un poco más extendido el configurar un servidor desde docker file?.

Añado un par de url que he consultado: 

https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/docker-for-dummies/

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/